# Arranging 3 kinds in a circle.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can 8 Indians, 4 Americans and 4 Englishmen sit around a table such that people of the same nationality sit together?

$3!\times8!\times(4!)^{2}$ ways we can arrange them in a row but, to arrange them in a circle, I didn't understand what we have to divide by, I think it would be $\frac{3!\times8!\times(4!)^{2}}{12}$, But I am not sure about the answer. Can anyone help me solve this problem?.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual convention in circular permutation problems is that two arrangements are considered to be equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by a rotation.

We can do this problem in two steps.  First, we arrange three blocks: A, E, I (representing the Americans, English, and Indians) in a circle.  There are two ways to do this since E has to be to the left or right of A.  Using your formula, we can obtain the same result by dividing the $3!$ ways of arranging the letters A, E, I in a row by $3$, which yields
$$\frac{3!}{3} = 2$$
Once we have established the relative order of the Americans, English, and Indians, we can arrange the Americans within their block of seats in $4!$ ways, the English within their block of seats in $4!$ ways, and the Indians within their block of seats in $8!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$2 \cdot 4!4!8!$$
ways to arrange four Americans, four English, and eight Indians in a circle if all people of the same nationality sit together.

Comment: If some of the people have problems hearing on one ear it matters who is to the left/right of them, but else I would think that you need to divide by two to account for the possibility to flip a configuration.

Comment: @user The usual convention for circular permutations is that two permutations that can be obtained from each other by a rotation are considered to be equivalent.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity  The usual convention for circular permutations is that two permutations that can be obtained from each other by a rotation are considered to be equivalent.  We would have to divide the answer by $2$ if two arrangements were considered equivalent if each person had the same two neighbors, in which case two arrangements would be considered equivalent if they could be obtained from each other by a rotation and/or a reflection.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thankyou for ur answer, ur answer thought me how to think.